# convert c++ code to c# in declaring an array

Tags: c#, c++, dynamic-arrays

recently i want to convert some codes from opencv to c#. But I have some problem in declaring the dynamic array in c++.

```
int* memorySteps = 0;
CV_CALL( memorySteps = new int [ 10*sizeof(memorySteps[0]) ]);
```

I want to convert it to a normal c# int array. The problem is the length.In c++, the declaration above seems that the compilor will create an array with 40 int elements(coz the sizeof the type memorySteps[0] is 4, 4 bytes length.). Is my understanding correct? However, it doesnt make sense because actually in the algorithm I only need an array of 10 int elements. So can anyone give me a hint which is right in the following(in c#), or can anyone show me other examples:

```
int[] memorySteps =new int [10*sizeof(int)];
```

or

```
int[] memorySteps =new int [10];
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of finding bugs in someone else's code!

Comment: Yes, that C++ code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; the C++ version will create an array of 40 integers, assuming `sizeof(int)==4`. It may be that the author was getting mixed up with C's `malloc`, which takes a size in bytes.

So your first version will give the same behaviour, and the second is more likely to give the intended behaviour - but there is a danger that the extra-large buffer was hiding other bugs, which might suddenly be exposed if you reduce the size.

Comment: I wrote a loop to check the length of the dynamic array. `for(int n=0;memorySteps[n];++n ){} `. the result of n should be (in my understanding) 40, but it returns the result of 44. It really confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

If the algorithm needs ten items, then use

```
int[] memorySteps =new int [10];
```

I suspect that the C++ code was itself ported from C code, where the programmer called `malloc`, like this:

```
memorySteps = malloc(10*sizeof(memorySteps[0]));
```

Whoever converted that code to C++ has probably forgotten to take away the multiplier. This has resulted in a functionally correct, yet somewhat memory inefficient code (although wasting 30 bytes these days hardly even counts as inefficient).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
int[] steps = new int [10];
```